# restore .tex and structure fles after turn off wile compiling

Tags: errors, compiling

i'm working with a large document when battery´s low charge forced to turn off the laptop just when i was compiling. 
It seems that all structure is damaged, and i can´t open any documen but only the DVI with an old version. It is possible to restore the .tex file? Im using texmaker, and the autosave is not active...

Comment: first save everything. from the dvi file you should be able to get yor text to save retyping but all the latex commands are gone. You should always have a backup/restore available for any document. Restoring is really an operating system (or editor) feature so not really directly related to tex.

Comment: that is what i was afraid :( ... Thank you..

Comment: the dvi file should be there as a last resort but are you sure that the data has really gone that sounds very strange, evn if the file system is distorted it may be possible to use file recovery tools to restore the data, it's highly unlikely the disk was physically erased.

Comment: the files are there.... but not even with the notepad are visible, except for the .BBL file. From DVi file, the link  to source is broken, the PDF is corruputed ...i tried some recovery tool onine for the PDF but  nothing....
Im already working in PDF from tis morning, fortunately is only the recent work what i have to retype...and the latex commands...Thanks